# How should we update list inside another list variable without effect parent list in angular

Tags: angular, angular6, angular8

I have following list of data.

```
subscriberDataList
        -> wipEligibilityList
        -> dependentList

dependentList
        -> wipEligibilityList
        -> eligibilityList

wipEligibilityList[0]
        -> status
        -> amountPending

eligibilityList[0]
        -> status
        -> amountPending
```

**Question is** How should I update `dependentList.wipEligibilityList.status` from dependentList.eligibilityList.status ? But not update for `subscriberDataList.wipEligibilityList.status and amountPending.`
If I am doing like below, It was impacted to `subscriberDataList.wipEligibilityList.status` and `subscriberDataList.wipEligibilityList.amountPending` also.

```
this.subscriberDataList.dependentList.forEach(dependent => {
    dependent.wipEligibilityList.forEach(wipEiligible => {
        dependent.eligibilityList.forEach(eligibile => {
            if(wipEiligible.status) {
                if(eligibile.status && eligibile.status === 'ACTIVE' && eligibile.amountPending === 'NO' ) {
                    wipEiligible.status = eligibile.status;
                    wipEiligible.amountPending = eligibile.amountPending;
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: it is easy to undersstand your problem if you properly provide your list data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case, the problem seems to be the way you're building the dependent list originally. If it's the same data, you should create it in a way it's not the same reference (down to the level of the objects inside the list):

```js
subscriberDataList.dependentList = 
  JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(subscriberDataList.wipEligibilityList));
```

After that, you can follow your logic and it will be independent data. `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(...))` will create a deep copy of your list, and this avoids any changes made in the objects of one list to reflect in the other list.

If the dependent list is a filtered copy of the original one, you can rebuild it before iterating through the objects:

```js
subscriberDataList.dependentList = 
  JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(subscriberDataList.dependentList));
```

You can also use a library, like [fast-copy](https://github.com/planttheidea/fast-copy) to build a deep clone of your original data in an efficient way:

```js
import copy from 'fast-copy';

...

subscriberDataList.dependentList = copy(subscriberDataList.dependentList);
```

Comment: Thank you so much @julianobrasil for quick response. But here, once I updated data dependentList.wipEligibilityList, how should I reassign to subscriberDataList.dependentList? I tried to reassign like below.  this.subscriberDataList.dependentList = tempDependentList; but not working

Comment: Able to see old status in this.subscriberDataList.dependentList.wipEligibilityList[0].status value. Not updated properly.

Comment: After deep clone, I make it dependentList as empty. Post update status, assign to this.subscriberDataList.dependentList. Now it's working fine. :).